# Django, how to override slugify function

Tags: python, django

I want my colons slugified into dashes instead of empty strings. I guess I could put something like `slugify(self.name.replace(":", "-"))` into my `save()` methods but that wouldn't be DRY at all (I think).

Also I could add that `.replace()` operation directly into `django.utils.text.slugify`

```
def slugify(value):
    value = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', value).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    value = value.replace(":", "-")
    value = re.sub('[^\w\s-]', '', value).strip().lower()
    return mark_safe(re.sub('[-\s]+', '-', value))
```

This doesn't seem like a good idea. How do I do it with regex?

1. How do I do it with regex?
2. How do I tie this override to a project rather than doing it inside django package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would implement a custom `slugify` function within your project with the desired changes:

```
def myslugify(value):
    return slugify(value.replace(":", "-"))
```

You can use this function in your `save()` methods of your models. This keeps your code free from "magic" as others would expect `slugify` to work the way Django implemented it.